# Log4j 2 logs in the wrong level

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I'm using log4j2 Version 2.3.

The Logger `de.ulrich` in my Tomcat Webapp is logging on level DEBUG, although I configured level INFO (see below). Why?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Filters>
        <!-- onMatch="DENY" es wird nicht geloggt, onMatch="ACCEPT" es wird geloggt -->
        <MarkerFilter marker="HTTP_HEADER" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <MarkerFilter marker="XML_FILTER" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <MarkerFilter marker="FLOW" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    </Filters>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="dmFileAppender" fileName="logs/doorman.log"
                     filePattern="logs/doorman-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <!--<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %X{id} %X{username} %-5level %c{36} %l: %msg%n</pattern>-->
                <pattern>%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss} %-5level [%t] %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy min="1" max="5"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="de.ulrich" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="dmFileAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.apache.http.impl.conn" level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="dmFileAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.http.impl.client" level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="dmFileAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.http.client" level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="dmFileAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Additional Info**
This is the path to log4j2.xml:
`.../webapp/myApp/WEB-INF/classes`

I'm sure that log4j can find this file, because it uses all the settings concerning `RollingFile`.

Comment: Where is this configuration file? In the default location or are you specifying its location with a system property?

Comment: Please try to remove statement after statement, until you have found your minimum configuration, that still reproduces the issue.

Comment: I found there is a connection to the elements `MarkerFilter`. The Java statements `logger.debug(FLOW, "message")` produce an logging output when the level `INFO` is set. I'll read the manual and give feedback tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the `Filters` element inside the `Logger` element, and now I get the expected logging output.

Fragment:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="warn">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="de.lgn" level="${lgnDefaultLogLevel}" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="dmFileAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <Filters>
            <!-- onMatch="DENY" es wird nicht geloggt, onMatch="ACCEPT" es wird geloggt -->
            <MarkerFilter marker="HTTP_HEADER" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="XML_FILTER" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="FLOW" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        </Filters>
    </Logger>
    ...
    ...
</Loggers>
```

Thank you.